# CPPredicateEditor is blank

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I'm building a web application with the Cappuccino framework, and I'm using the new Xcode integration through the XcodeCapp-Cocoa listener. When I place an NSPredicateEditor into a nib file (like MainWindow.xib), and allow it to be converted into a cib (for Cappuccino), the predicate editor is empty, and all that remains is a border and background colour where the CPScrollView is. I have tried modifying the predicate row templates, but have had no luck... Any suggestions?

[image: Xcode/Interface Builder NIB file]

[image: Cappuccino Application when run]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the answer. You actually need to **give** the CPPredicateEditor a predicate before it will show anything at all.

Comment: Im facing the same problem in a cappuccino project using the same xcodecapp setup and can't figure out how to give the CPPredicateEditor a predicate... I would expect it to work with data source methods but since it doesn't I'm kind of at a loss. Can you maybe post the part of your code where you pass a predicate to the editor?

Comment: [aPredicateEditor setObjectValue:aPredicate];

Comment: I did this but it didn't work. Connecting the CPPredicateEditor with a binding through IB did the trick though. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I found out why it failed... going to make a post about it

Answer (score 1):

As stated in my comments on @Luke Fletcher's reply to the question, my first attempt to add `[aPredicateEditor setObjectValue: aPredicate]` to the code didn't work.

**Here's why:** 
I was calling it from within my `initWithCib:bundle:` method. It seems the settings you change on your `CPPredicateEditor` in this function are overwritten by the settings in your cib as entered in IB. To get around this, I moved the code to `awakeFromCib` and it worked fine.

However if you use bindings, the `CPPredicate` object you reference in the binding will automatically be updated by the `CPPredicateEditor` when making changes, while I had the problem this wasn't the case when using the `setObjectValue:` method. To retrieve my changes there, I had to collect the `objectValue` of the `CPPredicateEditor` object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest posting the question to our mailing list. The guy who wrote that particular component frequents there, but I dont think monitors SO.

Alternatively you could do it all in code.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out, but thanks @Me1000! Great job on your TimeTable app and CPTableView implementation btw! Exceptional work!